# How can i upload mm icon for existing Multimedia Type

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager, multimedia

I upload mm icon for existing Multimedia Type, Word document(application/msword).

but when i push "save and close" button, show the error like above.

[image]

and i show the error log.

```
Unable to create icon for Multimedia Type.
 Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Themes\Carbon2\Images\MMIcons\mt.4.32x32.png' is denied.


at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtender.MultiplyUploadedIcon(String uploadIconPath, String destDir, String prefix, String iconType, Int32 size)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtender.CreateIconsSet(String iconPath, String destDir, String[] extensions, String itemId, Int32 size)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtender.PostProcessGetMultimediaType(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtender.ProcessGetItemResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtender.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ProcessResponse>b__3(DataExtender extender)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderParameterInspector.AfterCall(String operationName, Object[] outputs, Object& returnValue, Object correlationState)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

but i upload mm icon for new Multimedia Type, ogg(video/ogg).
i success to upload like above.

[image]

**so,
why can't upload mm icon for existing Multimedia Type ?**

Comment: Perhaps this cause "Right".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a Windows security issue.

My guess is that the appropriate user account only has *Write* permissions to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Themes\Carbon2\Images\MMIcons`. If you give the account *Modify* permissions, the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I receive the same error message when I attempt to change an existing icon. I also edited the permissions on the MMIcons folder to for *modify* permissions. It may be necessary to change permissions on the entire folder path.

Have you also checked to make sure that the image is roughly the same file size as the one it's replacing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms and kept on "Saving and Closing", eventually it managed to save the icon... (at the fourth save & close attempt)